# Is there a way to prevent passing "new T" to my observer_ptr constructor?

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator

I want to implement my own `observer_ptr` class which I want to use to indicate no ownership of a pointer. I'm wondering if it'd be possible to somehow prevent someone from using the following syntax:

`observer_ptr<T> var_name(new T);`

since it would completely invalidate the whole purpose of this class and lead to memory leaks. My guess would be that I would have to delete/make private a certain type of constructor, but I don't know what argument type I should choose to achieve that.

I'm not writing any sharable library, I'm asking more for myself so I can learn.

Comment: You could only have constructors from `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` and not from raw T. In that way you'd force yourself to safety allocate the pointer. That does cut down on the usefulness of the class though as you couldn't point to a stack object, or a member or other non-owning pointers.

Comment: Take a reference instead of a pointer? hopefully having to do `observer_ptr<T> var_name(*(new T))` would make your users think about what they're doing

Comment: make the constructor explicit, and have code review

Comment: Sadly there is only so much stupid you can protect against.

Comment: yeah I figured out that if someone wants to use something without knowing how to use it properly, I can't always protect them from their own ignorance or stupidity. Guess I'll just leave it "unprotected"

Comment: Why should an observer be fed by `new` object?! What is your pointer supposed to observe?! Validity of the object or just its value?!

Comment: For observer pointers either (a) use a raw pointer if you can guarantee the lifetime of the observed object or (b) use a `std::weak_ptr` if you can't guarantee the observed object's lifetime and have no other way to null-out raw observer pointer(s).

Comment: Richard has the right of it. So long as allow a raw pointer, you're stuck with no defenses against people being stupid with the observed object. But if you demand at least a weak pointer, you know the provided object is taken care of and have something you can check to make sure the observed object has not gone out of scope.

Comment: Except that you can't create a `weak_ptr` to a `unique_ptr`, so you wouldn't be able to observe a `unique_ptr` without converting it to a `shared_ptr` first. Also, using `weak_ptr` doesn't stop objects from going out scope (ie, in a multi-threaded setup), all it does is ensures the `weak_ptr` is emptied if the object does get destroyed before the `weak_ptr` is destroyed

Comment: Obviously if you are going the `weak_ptr` route you have to start with `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Is not the new terminology for non ownership a `view`? Or you could consider it a `span` of 1 element (or zero for no elements). Or you could pass a reference (the standard way of passing something where ownership is not transfered).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you accept the input `T*` pointer by a non-const reference, users can't call `new` directly in the constructor call, as the reference won't be able to bind to the temporary that `new` returns, eg:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class observer_ptr
{
public:
    observer_ptr(T*& ptr);
    ...
};
```

```cpp
observer_ptr<T> var_name(new T); // error!
```

They would be required to use a local `T*` variable instead, making them more aware of their responsibility for the lifetime of the object they create, eg:

```cpp
T *ptr = new T;
observer_ptr<T> var_name(ptr); // OK!
```

Note, however, that this approach does prevent users from being able to *directly* observe non-dynamic objects whose addresses are taken by `operator&` or `std::addressof()`, as well as `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` objects, eg:

```cpp
T obj;
observer_ptr<T> var_name(&obj); // error!
```

```cpp
auto ptr = make_unique<T>(); // or make_shared()
observer_ptr<T> var_name(ptr.get()); // error!
```

This would also require the use of a local `T*` pointer, eg:

```cpp
T obj;
T* ptr = &obj;
observer_ptr<T> var_name(ptr); // OK!
```

```cpp
auto obj = make_unique<T>(); // or make_shared()
T* ptr = obj.get();
observer_ptr<T> var_name(ptr); // OK!
```

You can avoid that if you add some additional constructors to `observer_ptr`, eg:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class observer_ptr
{
private:
    T* m_ptr;
public:
    observer_ptr(T*& ptr) : m_ptr(ptr) {}
    observer_ptr(T& obj) : m_ptr(addressof(obj)) {}
    observer_ptr(const unique_ptr<T>& ptr) : m_ptr(ptr.get()) {}
    observer_ptr(const shared_ptr<T>& ptr) : m_ptr(ptr.get()) {}
    observer_ptr(unique_ptr<T>&&) = delete;
    observer_ptr(shared_ptr<T>&&) = delete;
    ...
};
```

```cpp
T obj;
observer_ptr<T> var_name(obj); // OK!
```

```cpp
auto ptr = make_unique<T>(); // or make_shared()
observer_ptr<T> var_name(ptr); // OK!
```

```cpp
observer_ptr<T> var_name(make_unique<T>()); // error!
```

```cpp
observer_ptr<T> var_name(make_shared<T>()); // error!
```

Comment: In the last version I'd recommend adding `observer_ptr(std::unique_ptr<T>&&) = delete;` since creating a temporary `std::unique_ptr` would be dangerous `observer_ptr ptr = std::make_unique<int>(666);`

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to put such a restriction on the constructor parameter. If you take a pointer, it can be any pointer (of compatible type).

However in my opinion it's not something you should enforce with the language, but rather with a contract and the class intention, because if you look at smart pointer classes they also accept any pointer type and completely rely on documentation and common sense when it comes to what kind of pointer they take:

```cpp
int stackValue;
std::unique_ptr myPtr{ &stackValue }; // it will be UB upon myPtr destruction but compiles anyway
```

Also, a raw pointer `T*` is conventional way of expressing some pointer an object doesn't own. So you might be re-inventing the wheel here and may want to rethink this intention.

Answer (score 0):

One way or another you'll need to be able to pass a (smart) pointer or a reference to create an `observer_ptr` and the user will always be able to screw this up. You could make the user of your header state in a more obvious way though what they intend to do and hopefully have them think enough about the code they're writing to catch the error themselves.

You could accomplish this by adding a function for creating the `observer_ptr` and requiring its use via visibility restrictions. The following example requires the user to use `make_unowned_ptr(...)` for creating an `observer_ptr` for anything other than a null pointer:

```
template<class T>
class observer_ptr;

template<class T>
constexpr observer_ptr<T> make_unowned_ptr(T* ptr)
{
    return { ptr };
}

template<class T>
class observer_ptr
{
    T* m_ptr;

    constexpr observer_ptr(T* ptr)
        : m_ptr(ptr)
    {
    }

    friend constexpr observer_ptr<T> make_unowned_ptr<T>(T*);
public:
    constexpr observer_ptr(std::nullptr_t = nullptr)
        : m_ptr(nullptr)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    int value = 1;
    observer_ptr<int> ptr1(&value); // compiler error: constructor not visible
    auto ptr2 = make_unowned_ptr(&value); // ok
}
```